# Multiple notification push iPhone in PHP

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification

I've a little problem in my code

```
    <?php
        define("DB_HOST","");
        define("DB_USER","");
        define("DB_PASSWORD","");
        define("DB_DATABASE","");

        $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("erreur connection");
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

        //Make $i Global and set it to zero
        global $i;
        $i=0;
       //Make $j Global and set it to zero
        global $j;
        $j=0;
        //Makes $message global and defines the text for the message
        global $message;
        $message = "Hello everybody";
        //Gets the device token
        $result = mysql_query("select token FROM users_iphone");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
          //Gets the message string
          GLOBAL $message;
          //Gets the devicetoken from the database and sets a string with the token
          $devicetoken = $row['deviceToken'];
          //Calls the function to send the message and defines parameter for the function. In this case the device token and the message to be sent.
          sendPOST($devicetoken, $message);
          //Gets $i, defined earlier and adds 1 to it for each device token in our database.  We are counting how many devicetokens we have.
          global $i;
          $i++;
       }
       //Function that sends our push notification
        function sendPOST ($deviceToken, $messageGlobal){
        $deviceToken = '<5398e918 2c303556 23dfff5e 2754ff54 e55106f9 8d07ea4b 96cd88ba 288f526f>';
    $deviceToken = str_replace('<', '', $deviceToken);
    $deviceToken = str_replace('>', '', $deviceToken);
    $deviceToken = str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken);
    //token is good with no space and no > and <

$passphrase = 'mypassphrase';
        //start of apns code
       $ctx = stream_context_create();
       stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
       stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
        $fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
        if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

        $body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $messageGlobal,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );
        $payload = json_encode($body);
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
       $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
         if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
       //end of apns code
       //gets $j and adds 1  
       global $j;
    $j++;
       fclose($fp);
       }
       //checks if $j is equal to $i.  If so it means all the messages were delivered to apns (This doesn't mean that all the messages will be delivered by apple.  It does mean that they were delivered to apple from us.
        if ($j==$i){
        echo "<h1><b>Message's Successfully delivered.</b></h1><br>";

        echo "<b>Message:</b> $message<br>";
        echo "<b>Messages Delivered: </b>$j out of $i";
        }
        //this checks to see if $i is greater that $j.  If not then that means something went wrong on our end.  Therefore we have not delivered all the messages from our end to apple successfully.  This could mean a bad connection or server failure/error.
        elseif ($i>$j){
        echo "<h1><b>Not all messages have been delivered (at least on our end).  $j out of $i messages were delivered on our end.</b></h1>";

            echo "<b>Message:</b> $message";
          echo "<b>Messages Delivered: </b>$j out of $i";
        }
         ?>
```

When i note $deviceToken directly in my php file the notification are recieve but when i want to recover deviceToken in my database it's doesn't work!

Please help me, my code contains some problem(s)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. At which point do you lose the token? What exactly happens? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: first, can you send notification to a single device?

Comment: Thanks, i ve no error messages, just i don't receive the notification, thzt can be derived from my recovery deviceToken in my database because if i write in the function sendPOST ,$deviceToken = '<5398e918 2c303556 23dfff5e 2754ff54 e55106f9 8d07ea4b 96cd88ba 288f526f>'; it's working

Comment: Yes when i send one single notification it's working

Answer (score 0):

- From my experience, if you do all your coding  and other stuffs right, BUT, have *invalid*(inserted during testing) tokens inside your database, and sending pushmessages to all devices in a loop, Push notifications WILL NOT BE SENT after the 1st faulty/invalid token, even if you have many more good tokens left. So, please check on this.
- [***APNS-php is an advanced API***](http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/) to help you with multiple sending, detecting faulty tokens etc. Well, ofcourse you can go without it, but testing of Pushnotification sending  takes almost 90% of development time, and this API and it's cool exception handling can rock your world!

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand... :s

Comment: Which part? is this not related to what you are asking? For me, it was tough to look at the whole code and follow.